# How to account for font swash with PHP and GD

Tags: php, image, fonts, gd, php-gd

I have the following code to print text on an image. I am also adding a debug box around the text. However, I noticed the text on the left lies outside of the box that PHP gives me with `imagettfbbox`.

[image]

This looks like an issue with the font swash. Is there anyway to account for this? Can I figure out the distance between the start of the swash and the actual position `imagettfbbox` gives to me?

I don't think this is an issue with the font, as I tried it with a few script style fonts and the results were similar.

```
<?php

$font       = 'scriptin.ttf';
$text       = 'Ipsum';
$size       = 30;
$image      = imagecreatetruecolor(200, 200);
$fontColour = imagecolorallocate($image, hexdec('11'), hexdec('11'), hexdec('11'));
$bgColour   = imagecolorallocate($image, hexdec('CC'), hexdec('CC'), hexdec('CC'));

imagefilledrectangle($image, 0, 0, 200, 200, $bgColour);

$dimensions = imagettfbbox($size, 0, $font, $text);
imagefilledrectangle(
    $image,
    $dimensions[0] + 40,
    $dimensions[7] + 50,
    $dimensions[2] + 40,
    $dimensions[3] + 50,
    imagecolorallocate($image, mt_rand(1, 180), mt_rand(1, 180), mt_rand(1, 180))
);

imagettftext(
    $image,
    $size,
    0,
    40,
    50,
    $fontColour,
    $font,
    $text
);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($image);
```

The code and font is available here: https://github.com/AydinHassan/image-swash-example

If you point a VHOST at the repository, you can just hit `swash.php`

Comment: it looks like you've not placed the box coloring correctly: the amount of space "missing" on the left looks identical to the amount of space "too much" on the right.

Comment: That's what I thought, but if I am, I can't see where I'm doing it wrong. I am using the information `imagettfbbox` is giving me.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php#97211 suggests this is a known, if inconvenient, bug.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans The baseline glitch/bug should only effect the height, not the width.

Comment: Can you convert the font to an SVG and use it's dimensions instead?

Comment: This might help you, this is how glyphs are described: http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/glyphs/glyphs-3.html

Comment: This library seems to be able to extract meta from fonts, you might find what you need here: https://github.com/PhenX/php-font-lib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Edit:*** This appears to be fixed in PHP [7.0.12](http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-7.php#7.0.12) (bug [#53504](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53504)) so the code below shouldn't be required.

---

Based on a [comment in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php#97357) I've written the following function to calculate and return the difference between where GD thinks the left side of the bounding box is and where the leftmost pixel is found:

```
function xadjust($size, $angle, $fontfile, $text)
{
    $bbox = imagettfbbox($size, $angle, $fontfile, $text);

    $width = $bbox[4] - $bbox[6]; // upper right x - upper left x;
    $height = $bbox[1] - $bbox[7]; // lower left y - upper left y;

    // create an image with height and width doubled to fit any 'swash'.
    $im = imagecreatetruecolor($width * 2, $height * 2);

    // set background color to opaque black.
    imagefill($im, 0, 0, 0x00000000);

    // draw the text in opaque white.
    imagettftext(
        $im,
        $size,
        0,
        $width / 2,
        $height,
        0x00ffffff,
        $fontfile,
        $text
    );

    // set the min-width to its possible maximum.
    $min_x = $width * 2;

    for ($x = 0; $x < $width * 2; $x++) {
        // each x-pixel (horizontal)
        for ($y = 0; $y < $height * 2; $y++) {
            // each y-pixel (vertical)
            if (imagecolorat($im, $x, $y) > 0) {
                // non-black pixel found!
                $min_x = min($x, $min_x);
            }
        }
    }

    imagedestroy($im);

    // return the difference between where GD thinks the bounding box is and
    // where we found the leftmost non-black pixel.
    return (($width / 2) - $min_x) - abs($bbox[0]);
}
```

This can be integrated to your script fairly easily:

```
$font       = 'scriptin.ttf';
$text       = 'Ipsum';
$size       = 30;
$image      = imagecreatetruecolor(200, 200);
$fontColour = imagecolorallocate($image, hexdec('11'), hexdec('11'), hexdec('11'));
$bgColour   = imagecolorallocate($image, hexdec('CC'), hexdec('CC'), hexdec('CC'));

imagefilledrectangle($image, 0, 0, 200, 200, $bgColour);

$xadjust = xadjust($size, 0, $font, $text); // 1. get the adjust value.

$dimensions = imagettfbbox($size, 0, $font, $text);
imagefilledrectangle(
    $image,
    $dimensions[0] + 40 - $xadjust, // 2. move the left-side of the box to the left.
    $dimensions[7] + 50,
    $dimensions[2] + 40 - $xadjust, // 3. move the right-side of the box to the left.
    $dimensions[3] + 50,
    imagecolorallocate($image, mt_rand(1, 180), mt_rand(1, 180), mt_rand(1, 180))
);

imagettftext(
    $image,
    $size,
    0,
    40,
    50,
    $fontColour,
    $font,
    $text
);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($image);
```

This gives me the following output:

[image: script result]

I've run it with a few other fonts and sizes and it seems to be accurate to within 1 pixel.

Comment: I ended up with something similar. Except I counted backwards, which shaved a lot of time off for large images. I also ran a preliminary check, running rendering the text in a  temporary image and checking if there was any pixels in the first column. I needed these optimisations as we will be bulk rendering these images. Thanks!